# Sapply() , combining commands

Tags: r, sapply

I was just playing around and trialling with R and I had trouble with combining my `sapply()` commands into one expression.

For example, my data table was called `height_weight`.

I want to calculate the usual summary statistics: `mean`, `median`, `max`, `minimum` and sample size from column `2` till `7`.

**Just as sample codes:**

I used this for mean:

```
sapply(height_weight[2:7],mean,na.rm=TRUE)

max;
sapply(height_weight[2:7],max,na.rm=TRUE)
```

I'm just wondering, how would I combine the two into one expression? I have tried simply placing them next to each other, however that shows an error message.

Comment: Not sure I understand your answer but to my best understanding try the following - x <- list(a=1:14, b=2:13, c=7:19), sapply(x[1:2],summary). Summary itself is a function

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do so.

E.g. use `summary` and subset for the appropriate rows

```
sapply(height_weight[2:7], summary)[c("Mean", "Max."), ]
```

Or use an unnamed custom function that combines the two measures as a result

```
sapply(height_weight[2:7], function(x) c(Mean=mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), Max=max(x, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

Placing the two functions besides each other won't work because you can give `sapply` only one function. Everything that follows will be passed on to that function. (I.e. if it is no parameter of `sapply`.)

Comment: Thank you, the first line of code worked. I managed to find the min of each column. However, if I wish to calculate something like the sample size of each column and the st dev of each column.Would I add something like, "sd" and "sample.size()" to sapply(height_weight[2:7], summary)[c("Mean", "Max."), ]...?

Comment: Hm each column in the data frame has the same length/size (?). And `sapply` works in the form _sapply(object, functionToApplyOnColumns, Parameter1ToPassToFunction, [Parameter2ToPassToFunction, etc.]_. So we used the `summary` function on each column. This gives a little more info than just mean and max, so we extracted just the two from the result. It would be best to provide a full reproducible example to show your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow. I understand that since the summary function includes mean,max and min...therefore we are able to see it.I am wondering how I would add sd() and sample.size() , since their both functions. I tried adding sd() before the summary function,        sapply(height_weight[2:7],sd, summary)[c("Mean", "Max."), ]   But I got this error, Error in if (na.rm) "na.or.complete" else "everything" : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical

Comment: As I said, sapply(height_weight[2:7], sd, summary) would pass the summary function to the sd function as a parameter, which doesn't make any sense. `rbind(sapply(height_weight[2:7], sd, na.rm=TRUE)`makes sense, as perhaps does `sapply(height_weight[2:7], sample.size)` (I dunno that function). You can also write custom functions, like I did in the 2nd example, which combine results. Or you may `rbind` the results of two `sapply`s and so on. Post a reproducible example that produces your error (read this http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Reproducibility.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the usual summary statistics, you can just use `summary`:

```
summary(height_weight[2:7])
sapply(height_weight[2:7],summary) # just to use sapply
```

Otherwise, if you want to define your own summary statistics (in this case mean and max), then you can write a function mysummary and use `sapply` just as before:

```
mysummary <- function(x, ...) {
  c(mean=mean(x, ...),  
    max=max(x, ...))    
}
sapply(height_weight[2:7], mysummary , na.rm=TRUE)
```